# Cordova/Phonegap: JQuery UI Accordion doesn't scroll anymore on ios8

Tags: jquery, cordova, ios8, accordion

I got an App for iOS  written within the cordova framework (html/css/js). To display contents it uses the Accordion from JQuery UI. The Accordion has fixed height so that the contents needs scrolling when it's to large for one page. Til the iOS8 Update everything worked fine, now i can't scroll the contents anymore. Scrolling works when i tap on the header of the accordion but not with then content.

Anyone an idea what could cause this?

Things i checked

 - cordova up to date

 - jQuery up to date

 - XCode up to date

 - with Safari Debugger i don't find any diferences in CSS

 - same App works on ios 7.1

 - difference in behaviour also present in emulator of xcode

Thanks

Christian

Comment: Just as update: It seems that overflow:scroll in CSS also doesn't work anymore. Probably this is used by jQuery? Any idea whether this is a bug in ios8 or something persistent?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to update my cordova to the latest (3.6.3) and my scrolling started working again.

**Update:**

I just ran across another issue that appears to break scrolling in iOS 8. I had been using [bouncefix.js](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/bouncefix.js), but it appears that this library isn't compatible with the latest cordova and iOS 8. Simply commenting out this javascript library re-enabled scrolling in my app.

Prior to iOS 8, bouncefix.js worked pretty well and didn't cause any issues with scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and was looking for the solution for a day, but I have fuond it. I am using Tocca.js: https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/Tocca.js instead of jQuery swipe event plugin, and it can handle both scroll and swipe events. Fortunately it is use the same function names, so you can simply change the .js files.

Thanks a lot for the answer at an other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23879655/2576454