# App no longer scrolls on IOS8

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ios8

I have a phonegap build application running the latest version that was working perfectly.
It uses Jquery Mobile to run. We've got a strange bug with any IOS8 device, the app can no longer scroll, so on a page that goes further than the content people can't swipe up to move down. I've ensured i'm using the latest phonegap, jquery and jquery mobile but i'm running out of ideas fast!

The app is laid out like the following, i've stripped out all the page containers as they all have the same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>name</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/name.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/photoswipe.css" />



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script src='js/spectrum.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/spectrum.css' />

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="Register">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >

        <h1>name</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="register" data-title="Home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
        <h1>name</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"><br /><br />
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Register</li>
            <li>
                <label for="registerUserName">Email Address*</label>
                <input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-1" class="validateR" valtext="Email" id="registerUserName" value="" type="text">
                <label for="registerPassword">Password*</label>
                <input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-3" class="validateR" valtext="Password" id="registerPassword" value="" type="password">
                <label for="registerPasswordConf">Password Confirmation*</label>
                <input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-3" class="validateR" valtext="Password" id="registerPasswordConf" value="" type="password">
                <label for="registerFirstName">First Name*</label>
                <input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-1" class="validateR" valtext="First Name"id="registerFirstName" value="" type="text">
                <label for="registerSurname">Surname*</label>
                <input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-1" class="validateR" valtext="Surname" id="registerSurname" value="" type="text">
                <label for="registerSurname">Postcode*</label>
                <input data-clear-btn="true" name="text-1" class="validateR" valtext="Postcode" id="registerPostcode2" value="" type="text">

            </li>
            <li>
                <div style="float:right">
                    <a data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Back</a>
                    <a id="registerBtnRegister" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">Register</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/Global.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/SendMessage.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/Mapping.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/Google.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/GetCoOrds.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/onpageshows.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/Login.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/Register.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/AddPictures.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/MyProfile.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/EditPet.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/markfound.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/IAP.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/data/DeviceReady.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova/Phonegap: JQuery UI Accordion doesn't scroll anymore on ios8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950558/cordova-phonegap-jquery-ui-accordion-doesnt-scroll-anymore-on-ios8)