# Simple Javascript code question about counting points and score

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a popcat game parody. I have this simple code in JS for scoring points:

```
// touch event

img.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){

    increaseScore();
    img.src = 'popcat2.png';
    audio.play();
});

img.addEventListener("touchmove", function(){

    img.src = 'popcat1.png';
     audio.play();
});
```

But whenever I try to use this on my mobile it doubles the score: one for event `touchstart` and another for `touchmove`, instead of scoring one time. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: See also [prevent touchstart when swiping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069458/prevent-touchstart-when-swiping)

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].